# Using a personal certificate to authenticate in an Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, certificate, jira

We have a Jira server that uses a personal certificate for authentication followed by a standard user/password authentication. This personal certificate is typically installed the Windows certificate store, for example. A typical scenario is when opening the Jira website, the user is prompted to choose a certificate to authenticate with. Once authenticated, the user is then prompted for a username and password.

The problem for me comes in when interfacing to the Jira server from our Jenkins instance. The plugin that I am using to connect to the Jira server does not support the personal certificate authentication scheme. Someone gave me an idea to use a reverse proxy to authenticate with the Jira server configured with the personal certificate of the service account that I am using to connect with the Jira server.

I've gotten to the point of creating a reverse proxy using Apache, but I can't seem to get the right configuration so that Apache passes the personal certificate to the Jira server when it connects to it.

Answer (score 0):

Apache cannot just pass the certificate, because authentication is not done by just sending the certificate: it is done as part of the TLS handshake by making a digital signature of a "challenge" sent by the server, which acts as a proof that you own the certificate *and* its private key (without sending the private key itself).

Usually such protocols are deliberately designed to *prevent* the handshake from being "relayed" to another server – that is, if your whole TLS connection is with Apache, then you're also authenticating to Apache and nobody else. This is a security feature to make sure that malicious webservers cannot stash your certificate & proof for later use and make requests impersonating you.

But it sounds like the suggestion you received was to use the reverse proxy for Jenkins only, and to create an authentication certificate for the reverse proxy *itself* instead of having it relay the auth.

(Indeed having it relay the authentication as-is doesn't make sense because then you're just back to your initial problem: Jenkins doesn't support sending a certificate, so what exactly is the proxy going to relay?)

The point of the reverse proxy is to *convert* to a completely different authentication mechanism:

1. Jenkins uses simple username & password to authenticate to the proxy. (Not Jira username/password, but just a dedicated username/password that you configure in the proxy server itself, e.g. via Apache "AuthType Basic" – to make sure no one except Jenkins is allowed to use the proxy.)
2. The proxy uses *its own* personal certificate to authenticate to Jira, and you assign it the permissions that Jenkins would need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess what confuses me is that the statement "The proxy uses its own personal certificate." What is the difference with using the personal certificate that I am currently using for the Jenkins service? It's encrypted with a password so web servers couldn't arbitrarily use it. Just to be clear, Jenkins is not sending the personal certificate. I want to configure the reverse proxy to use the personal certificate. Albeit using it along with a private key.